# Should I use a data TABLE if I need ONLY one row of data?

Tags: asp.net, sql, select, datatable

I do a SQL SELECT and always get back one row of data.

What is the simplest structure that I can use besides using a table?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing would probably be a `DataReader`. Here's an [MSDN sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz.aspx) on how to read data with a `DataReader`.

Answer (score 0):

yah its absolutely right that you have to use the datareader, because there is only one row so you dont need to move backward and datareader is forward only, so you dont have anyproblem with that.